# Delete intersection columns in 2xN matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices A and B (of size 2xN) in matlab of the form:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6
   7 8 9 4 1 9]

B=[7 4 3 5 1 8
   7 8 9 4 7 9]
```

I want to look for the intersection of A and B column by colmun, i.e., I want to delete column 1 and column 3 of matrix A and column 3 and column 5 of matrix B of my above example. Is there a way to do this without loops? Is there a function that do this in matlab?

P.S. The matrices could be of different sizes, i.e., for example, one can has size 2x10 the other can has size 2x20.

Comment: Will the matching columns always be in the same positions?

Comment: No. It can be in two different columns of the two matrices.

Comment: Please update your example data to include such a case then

Comment: Oh and also can there be repeated columns within a matrix?

Comment: See my edited solution for your latest requirements

Comment: No. I do not see repeated columns within a matrix. Do you mean column with the same element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `ismember` by transposing and looking for matching rows across the two matrices.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6
   7 8 9 4 1 9];

B=[7 4 3 5 1 8
   7 8 9 4 7 9];


ind_A = ~ismember(A', B', 'rows')';
ind_B = ~ismember(B', A', 'rows')';

A(:, ind_A)

ans =

     2     4     5     6
     8     4     1     9



B(:, ind_B)

ans =

     7     4     5     8
     7     8     4     9
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it and it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

A single call to [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) will get you the locations of the intersecting columns in *both* arrays:

```
>> [C,IA,IB] = intersect(A',B','rows')
C =
     1     7
     3     9
IA =
     1
     3
IB =
     5
     3
```

Remove them (inherently stable output order):

```
>> A(:,IA) = []
A =
     2     4     5     6
     8     4     1     9
>> B(:,IB) = []
B =
     7     4     5     8
     7     8     4     9
```

---

Or you can call [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) twice:

```
>> A2 = setdiff(A.',B.','rows','stable').'
A2 =
     2     4     5     6
     8     4     1     9
>> B2 = setdiff(B.',A.','rows','stable').'
B2 =
     7     4     5     8
     7     8     4     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute a `size(A,1)`x`size(B,2)` matrix that tells, for each combination of columns, whether they are equal or not (with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)). Then use that to select which columns should be kept in `A` and `B`:

```
ind = squeeze(any(bsxfun(@ne, A, permute(B, [1 3 2])))); %// 1 if different
A = A(:,all(ind,2)); %// keep a column of A if it differs from all columns in B
B = B(:,all(ind,1)); %// keep a column of B if it differs from all columns in A
```